# Generate unique numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make array of seven random numbers so far this is my code:

```
function lotoGenerator() {
        var array = [];
        var i;
    for (i = 0; i <=6; i++) {
        var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 39) + 1);
        array.push(temp);
    }    
    console.log(array);
}
lotoGenerator();
```

Now with this code I can get results like this [30, 6, 36, 8, 16, 27, 6].
As you can see number 6 come out two times.
Is there a way to make array not repeat numbers.
I'm new to javaScript and I wasn't able to implement solutions I found online.

Comment: Do you want  to always get 7 distinct numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a `do ... while` statement on your random generation that check if the number was already on the loto numbers.

```
function lotoGenerator() {
        var array = [];
        var i;
    for (i = 0; i <=6; i++) {
        do {
            // Generate your random number
            var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 39) + 1);
            // If the number already exists, the index of it on loto array will be different of -1, so it already exists
            var alreadyExists = array.indexOf(temp) !== -1;
        } while (alreadyExists) // Repeat this many times necessary to get an unique number.

        array.push(temp);
    }    
    console.log(array);
}
lotoGenerator();
```

Note that this isn't the most efficient solution since you can have the bad luck of having the same number sorted many times, so the `do...while` loop may run too many times.

The best way to solve this is by having an array with available numbers and removing the drawn number:

```
function lotoGenerator() {
    var available = [];
    var drawn = [];
    for (var i = 1; i<= 40; i++) {
        available.push(i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i <=6; i++) {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * available.length));
        drawn.push(available[random]);
        available.splice(random, 1);
    }

    return drawn;
}
```

This second function have an well known execution time, and will be more efficient as the number of random elements increase.

Comment: can i use goto statement here ??

Comment: @mahi Javascript do not implement goto statement, also a `do..while` block is easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain "var alreadyExists = array.indexOf(temp) !== -1; "  in more detail. I'm trying to grasp the concept but i'm having trouble.

Comment: @Karadjordje it will find the index of element from array . if it don't fin it will return `-1`

Comment: One more question in your second solution. Why did you use "available.splice(random, 1);" ???

Comment: Array splice removes the element from the available array. It avoids that the number was choiced twice.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the options:

```
function lotoGenerator() {
    var array = [], i = 0, temp;
    while (i <= 6) {
        temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 39) + 1);
        if ( array.indexOf(temp) > -1 ) continue;
        i = array.push(temp);
    }    
    console.log(array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `if(array.indexOf(temp) > -1) continue;` will do the trick to your code.

```js
function lotoGenerator() {
        var array = [];
    while (array.length <= 6) {
        var temp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 39) + 1);
        if(array.indexOf(temp) > -1) continue;
        array.push(temp);
    }    
    console.log(array);
}
lotoGenerator();
```